# запретить выполнение функции при последующих кликах

Tags: javascript, функции, click

здесь пример https://codepen.io/agafron/pen/pdQNJJ?editors=1010

как запретить выполнение функций StartTir() и startDemo() при многократных кликах на кнопку NewGame или старт, или по очереди на NewGame/старт?

при поочередном нажатии на NewGame/старт происходит наложение изображений друг на друга.

как правильно задать условия?

извиняюсь, если не очень корректно задал вопрос, просто не знаю как это более конкретно изложить.

по возможности изменения нужны в этой части:

```
    newGame.onclick = function () {
    //loadWord(); 
    if(!button.classList.contains('demo')) {
        button.classList.toggle('demo');

            endGame();
            startDemo(); 
     }
}
          button.onclick = function () {
            if(!button.classList.contains('play')){
            button.classList.toggle('play');

                endDemo();
                //getWords();
                startTir();

            }

        };
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Ваш код уже это делает.

Comment: @Igor, не делает

Comment: @Grundy значит, я его не понял

Comment: @Igor, так можно это как-то сделать? или надо изменять код игры?